# Error while running task - TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am use Sencha Ext.js I am starting a task in my ViewController by calling startTask() below.

```
Ext.define('Thingor.view.main.ThingGridController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',


   ...


   checkThingStatusResponse: function(result) {
            console.log('result was');
            console.log(result);
            var fail = true;
            var actionMessages = new Array;
            var failMessages = new Array;
            var gotFail = false;
            var gotSuccess = false;


            if (result != undefined) {
               for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
                  if (result[x] != undefined) {
                     var thisResult = result[x]; 
                     var rc = thisResult.status;
                     if (rc != undefined) {
                        if (rc != 204 && rc != 200 ) {
                           fail = false; gotFail = true; console.log('perm error');
                        } else {
                           for (var thingStat = 0; thingStat < thisResult.results.length; thingStat++) {
                              var tresult = thisResult.results[thingStat];
                              fail = false;
                              gotSuccess = true;
                              console.log('thing ' + tresult._oid + ' has ' + tresult.status);
                              if( tresult.status == 'Ready' ) {
                                 this.view.store.load();
                                 // stop task here but how?
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
            ...
         }, // end checkThingStatusResponse




   checkThingStatus: function (thgOid) {
        this.myAsyncExec(
                        Thingor.Utils.globals.apiEndpoint + '/Thing/' + thgOid
                ,       ''
                ,       'GET'

                ,       ''
                ,       'checkThingStatusResponse'
                ,       this.id
        );
   }
   , startTask: function (thgOid) {
        console.log('Starting task for new Thing[' + thgOid + "]");
        Ext.TaskManager.start({ run: this.checkThingStatus(thgOid), interval: 10000});
   }
   , stopTask: function (thgOid) {}
```

My task seems to run ok expect I get this error message:

```
[E] Error while running task - TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined     ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1437767086048:5683
```

I am causing this error somehow?
Also how would I stop my task?

Comment: The error doesn't appear in the code you've provided, it's happening somewhere else. `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` means that there is some undefined object where you're trying to call the method 'apply'. What is the context of your code? I think we'll need to see more than what you've provided.

Comment: Also I might take a look through this style guide, might help with some code readability: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Comment: I also see lots of usages of things like the abstract comparison operator `!=` instead of the strict operator `!==`, where the former almost always inevitably leads to errors because of typecasting. This may or may not be related to any issues you're having in your code.

Comment: I guess this more a 'Sencha Ext.js' issue than a javascript issue.